# custom dropdown for two UIButton iOS

Tags: ios, delegates

I'm trying to implement a custom dropdown menu(searched code over the internet) and using it for two UIButtons.
When button is pressed a tableView appears.
I implemented it for one UIButton and I'm trying to implement it for another button, but I am not sure how it will know which object is calling the delegate.

In CustomDropDownView.m

```
@protocol DropDownViewDelegate

@required
- (void)dropDownCellSelected:(NSInteger)returnIndex;

@end

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [delegate dropDownCellSelected:indexPath.row];
    [self closeDropDown];

}
```

In ViewController.m

```
- (void)dropDownCellSelected:(NSInteger)returnIndex {
//here I've to decide which button is changed
    [self.reminderCategory setTitle:[reminderCategoryList objectAtIndex:returnIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

How would it know which button is  pressed. 
I've just started learning and struggling with delegates, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to use the tableView.tag property and set it to 1 or 2 if button 1 or 2 triggered its appearance. 
Then modify your protocol to:

```
-(void)dropDownCellSelected:(NSInteger)returnIndex forButtonNo:(NSInteger)button;
```

And call it like this:

```
[delegate dropDownCellSelected:indexPath.row forButtonNo:tableView.tag];
```